# How to convert the objects in a query result to custom type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I think the same question must have been asked, but I just don't know how to describe it properly.

I am using Entity Framework, and I have a table called vendor, consisting of many columns:

```
[vendor] 
 - [Id] [INT]
 - [Name] [NVARCHAR]
 - [ApiUrl] [NVARCHAR]
 - ...
```

I am writing a Web Api to expose the function which users can get vendor records by. However, I want to provide only three columns.

So I created a model class, as below:

```
public class OM_Vendor
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string ApiUrl { set; get; }
}
```

After building the model classes with EF, the context object of EF has a property named vendors now. Then, in an API controller, I coded like this:

```
var vendors = this.objEntity.vendors
.Where<OM_Vendor>(v => v.Status == "1")
.OrderBy(v => v.Id)
.Skip(intSkip)
.Take(intLimit)
.ToList();
```

It doesn't work, neither does this:

```
    var vendors = this.objEntity.vendors
.Where(v => v.Status == "1")
.OrderBy(v => v.Id)
.Skip(intSkip)
.Take(intLimit)
.ToList<OM_Vendor>();
```

Is there a way to convert the objects returned by the methods like above to my custom type?

Thanks a lot.

---

In addition, I know that I can get it to work in this way:

```
var vendors = new List<OM_Vendor>();
vendors = objCont.ExecuteStoreQuery<OM_Vendor>("SELECT * FROM vendor").ToList();
```

And this way works too:

```
var vendors = this.objCont.vendors
                .Where(v => v.Status == "1")
                .OrderBy(v => v.Id)
                .Select(
                    row => new
                        {
                            Id= row.Id,
                            Name = row.Name,
                            ApiUrl = row.ApiUrl
                        }
                )
                .Skip(intSkip)
                .Take(intLimit)
                .ToList();
```

---

Update:

According to @Andrew's answer, I updated my code as below:

```
public class OM_Vendor
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string ApiUrl { set; get; }

    public static implicit operator OM_Vendor(vendor vendor){
        return new OM_Vendor
        {
            Id = vendor.Id,
            Name = vendor.Name,
            ApiUrl = vendor.ApiUrl
        };
    }
}
```

And in my controller class:

```
List<OM_Vendor> vendors = this.objCont.vendors
                                        .Where(v => v.Status == "1")
                                        .OrderBy(v => v.Id)
                                        .Skip(intSkip)
                                        .Take(intLimit)
                                        .ToList();
```

I got error saying:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

What did I miss? As for the explicit cast, I will have to convert each instance explicitly in a loop?

Comment: so what is wrong with using the projection? seems as though you are asking if there is a different way to accomplish this, since you say that it works that way....

Comment: My question is that, can I do the projection without executing a SQL statement? Just project it directly from the vendors collection with my custom type class OM_Vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have 3 methods to achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

1. Use the `.Select()` linq extension method to create a projection (as is demonstrated by your last example.)  Generally a good option, as this will create a SQL expression which only returns the fields which are needed by your Data Transfer Object.
2. Create a custom cast operator, e.g. `public static implicit Operator OM_Vendor(Vendor vendor)`, which takes in a full `Vendor` object and assigns it to an instance of `OM_Vendor`.  The main drawback here is that you are essentially retrieving all fields through Entity Framework, only to Flatten the entity and discard many of these fields during the implicit cast.
3. Use a custom library such as [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to automate the process of converting the objects.  Suffers from most of the same issues as 2., but having it handled by a library can be helpful if you have many classes you are Flattening.

A more complete code example to demonstrate:

```
public class OM_Vendor {
    ...
    public static implicit Operator OM_Vendor(Vendor vendor){
        return new OM_Vendor {
            Id = vendor.Id;
            Name = vendor.Name;
            ApiUrl = vendor.ApiUrl;
    }
}

OM_Vendor om_Vendor = this.objEntity.vendors.Where(
...

List<OM_Vendor> vendors = this.objEntity.vendors.Where(
...
```

Either of these statements should execute correctly, using the `implicit Operator` as a Constructor when assigning a `Vendor` instance to an `OM_Vendor`.  However, it cannot be overstated, this is Flattening the object at the code level, and will result in a larger than necessary SQL query.

This actually should be an **explicit** operator, since data loss occurs during conversion.  Changing `implicit Operator` to `explicit Operator` will cause this conversion to require the cast, i.e. `OM_Vendor omVendor = (OM_Vendor)vendor;`.  This makes it much more clear that a conversion is occurring, but makes the code slightly more verbose.

Comment: which route did you end up taking?

Comment: Thank you Andrew, for your comprehensive answer. But I failed in compiling it; I have updated the post, adding my new code. Would you take a look, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm looking at the code and the error now... I'm not sure why it is trying to convert to a generic list and not the typed list, but I'm sure it's something we can work out

Comment: I'm guessing that this has something to do with how EF is materializing the rows for the intermediate query; I think you might have to issue a `.Select()` before the `.ToList()`

Comment: I put Select() brfore ToList(): `List<OM_Vendor> vendors = this.objEntity.vendors
           .Where(v => v.Status == "1")
           .OrderBy(v => v.Id)
           .Skip(intSkip)
           .Take(intLimit)
           .Select()
           .ToList();`
It doesn't work.

Comment: hmmm, ok do you know if the implicit operator is working at all? can you return a single vendor from your table and then try to do `OM_Vendor om_Vendor = vendor;` just to make sure there isn't an error there?

Comment: The `implicit operator` works, indeed. `var vendor = this.objEntity.vendors.SingleOrDefault(v => v.Id == id && v.Status == "1");

if (vendor != null)
{
 OM_Vendor v = vendor;
 ....
}`

Comment: before we continue, may I ask you a question, as your answers raised another interest of mine. Let's assume I do it with Select(), like: `var vendors = this.objCont.vendors .Where(v => v.Status == "1").OrderBy(v => v.Id).Select(row => new{Id= row.Id,Name = row.Name,ApiUrl = row.ApiUrl}).Skip(intSkip).Take(intLimit).ToList();`
And as you said, it will generate a SQL which only retrieve the three fields. Then, how about this: `var vendors = new List<OM_Vendor>();vendors = objCont.ExecuteStoreQuery<OM_Vendor>("SELECT * FROM vendor").ToList();`, will it retrieve all the fields before projecting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried projecting with:

```
.Select(row => new OM_Vendor{ Id=row.Id, Name=row.Name, ApiUrl=row.ApiUrl})
```

Comment: eh correct me if I'm wrong but that's not necessarily needed if you're not doing an aggregate function. Also, it's auto-selecting all anyways when you don't provide a select. So that can't be the reason why it wouldn't work for him. I don't understand why he's using `this.objEntity`, objEntity should be a context instance of a EF model. I think that may be his issue.

Comment: @JordanM, Thank you. The snippet shown is copied from an API controller class, and I declared objCont as a private member property of that class. I believe that it has nothing to do with my question. Hmmm.... I think so.